# Grant access to all Windows users in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is the scenario, using SQL Server 2005.

1 - I'm logged as administrator in Windows and SQL Server uses Windows authentication.

2 - I attached a new database using SQL Server Management Studio.

3 - At this point, only the current user can access the database. If i logout this user and login with a new (non-admin) user, this can't access.

I want ANY windows user get access to the DB and i don't want to include each user. Is there a way to do it ?

The machine is not logged to the network, it's only local users.

Thanks

Comment: A windows domain or individual PC?

Comment: @delphirules do you have an AD group that everyone belongs to?  If yes, give that group access to the DB.

Comment: Just edited the question with additional info.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 automatically creates local user groups for this I believe.  Check your Computer Management>Local Users and Groups for the "SQLServer2005" groups and add users accordingly.

Comment: Create a user in the db for that login and then you can give it any rights you want.